# Whois Parser that isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whois

I'm new to Rails and wanted to try the Ruby Whois gem.

I defined an Active Record record that creates a report. That report would then be filled with data from the whois query (preferably parsed).

When I do the query I get something really weird. I've used ByeBug as a debugger:

```
$ (byebug) Whois.whois("google.it")

"\n*********************************************************************\n* Please note
 that the following result could be a subgroup of      *\n* the data contained in the database.    


    *\n*                                                                   *\n* Additional 
information can be visualized at:                      
*\n* http://www.nic.it/cgi-bin/Whois/whois.cgi
*\n*********************************************************************\n\nDomain:             google.it\nStatus:             ok\nCreated:            1999-12-10
00:00:00\nLast Update:        2014-05-07 00:52:45\nExpire Date:        2015-04-21\n
\nRegistrant\n  Name:             Google Ireland Holdings\n  Organization:     Google 
Ireland Holdings\n  ContactID:        DUP430692088\n  Address:          70 Sir John 
Rogersons Quay\n                    Dublin\n                    2\n                    
IE\n                    IE\n  Created:          2013-04-21 01:05:35\n  Last Update:      
2013-04-21 01:05:35\n\nAdmin Contact\n  Name:             Tsao Tu\n  Organization:     Tu 
Tsao\n  ContactID:        DUP142437129\n  Address:          70 Sir John Rogersons 
Quay\n                    Dublin\n                    2\n                    
IE\n                    IE\n  Created:          2013-04-21 01:05:35\n  Last Update:      
2013-04-21 01:05:35\n\nTechnical Contacts\n  Name:             Google Ireland Holdings\n  
Organization:     Google Ireland Holdings\n  ContactID:        DUP430692088\n  
Address:          70 Sir John Rogersons Quay\n                    
Dublin\n                    2\n                    IE\n                    IE\n  
Created:          2013-04-21 01:05:35\n  Last Update:      2013-04-21 01:05:35\n
\nRegistrar\n  Organization:     MarkMonitor International Limited\n  Name:             
MARKMONITOR-REG\n  Web:              https://www.markmonitor.com/\n\nNameservers\n  
ns1.google.com\n  ns4.google.com\n  ns2.google.com\n  ns3.google.com\n\n"



$ (byebug) Whois.whois("google.it").parser

#<Whois::Record::Parser:0x000000065bdc30 

    @record="\n*********************************************************************\n* 
Please note that the following result could be a subgroup of      *\n* the data contained 
in the database.                               
*\n*                                                                   *\n* Additional 
information can be visualized at:                      *\n* http://www.nic.it/cgi-bin/Whois
/whois.cgi
*\n*********************************************************************
\n\nDomain:             google.it\nStatus:             ok\nCreated:  1999-12-10
00:00:00\nLast Update:        2014-05-07 00:52:45\nExpire Date:        2015-04-21\n
\nRegistrant\n  Name:             Google Ireland Holdings\n  Organization:     Google 
Ireland Holdings\n  ContactID:        DUP430692088\n  Address:          70 Sir John 
Rogersons Quay\n                    Dublin\n                    2\n                    
IE\n                    IE\n  Created:          2013-04-21 01:05:35\n  Last Update:      
2013-04-21 01:05:35\n\nAdmin Contact\n  Name:             Tsao Tu\n  Organization:     Tu 
Tsao\n  ContactID:        DUP142437129\n  Address:          70 Sir John Rogersons 
Quay\n                    Dublin\n                    2\n                    
IE\n                    IE\n  Created:          2013-04-21 01:05:35\n  Last Update:      
2013-04-21 01:05:35\n\nTechnical Contacts\n  Name:             Google Ireland Holdings\n  Organization:     Google Ireland Holdings\n  ContactID:        DUP430692088\n  
Address:          70 Sir John Rogersons Quay\n                    
Dublin\n                    2\n                    IE\n                    IE\n  
Created:          2013-04-21 01:05:35\n  Last Update:      2013-04-21 01:05:35\n
\nRegistrar\n  Organization:     MarkMonitor International Limited\n  Name:             
MARKMONITOR-REG\n  Web:              https://www.markmonitor.com/\n\nNameservers\n  
ns1.google.com\n  ns4.google.com\n  ns2.google.com\n  ns3.google.com\n\n">
```

I would like to know what all this is about. It isn't structured anything like it would be in IRB or on a simple console.

And when I try looking at the properties it just tells me to buzz off:

```
$ (byebug) Whois.whois("google.it").property_supported?(:domain)

NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `property_supported?' for #<Whois::Record:0x000000065aba08>
nil
```

I'm on a virtual machine (Ubuntu precise64) running Rails 4.0, and Ruby version 2.1.2. The web server is the default Webrick.

All I'd like to do is get the object `<Whois::Record>` and extract the values from it, such as domain, domain_id, registrar and so on... any tips ?

Comment: tried to make the code readable but only got so far

Comment: Please take the time to use correct grammar and formatting. It makes your question a lot easier to read, which helps us help you solve the problem. *NOT* doing that only discourages potential answerers, who figure you didn't care enough to write a readable question so why should they care enough to try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#whois` method returns a `Whois::Record` object which wraps the whois response string and provides parsing capabilities. The output you see in the console is just the object representation.

```
record = Whois.whois("google.it")
record.class
# => Whois::Record
```

The [Record](http://rubydoc.info/gems/whois/Whois/Record) documentation explains you how to use the object. For instance, to print out its String representation, explicitly call `puts` or use `.to_s`.

```
puts record.to_s
```

If you need to access a specific property, there is no need to invoke the parser. Simply access the property.

```
record.expires_on
# => 2015-04-21 00:00:00 +0200
```

Make sure to read the [library documentation](http://ruby-whois.org/).

Comment: Can't believe i got stuck because of a Ruby non Rails basic thingy. Thank you so much ! And yeah i did check over and over the documentation but i guess there are some subtleties i will miss no matter...

Answer (score 0):

1. The output in the console shows that making the call returns the output expected (setting `@record`).
2. `property_supported?` didn't work because that method is not available on this type of object.

Also I've never heard of byebug.
Are you able to do `rails console` from the root of the application and try using objects there ?

Comment: Well from what i understood, the rails debugger wasn't maintained for rails versions > 3.0 so i had to look for something else.

Byebug is actually quite easy to use, well i wouldn't really know since i haven't tried any other debugger though.

Comment: [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) is a very nice Ruby debugger for v2.0+